# About the Lagrange equation involving Coulomb interaction

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, variational-calculus

In the book by Prof Nagaosa, the Lagrange density was given by Eq. (1)
[image]    (1)

Then, according to the Euler-Lagrange equation (Eq.(2)), we can do the derivatives of Lagrange density (e.g., Eq. (1)) with respect to [image].

[image]    (2)

By doing so, the Book by Prof Nagaosa indicates the following result:
[image]    (3)

Why the factor $1/2$ in front of the integral (over **r**') disappear?

Comment: Isn't it because there are two \psi in the integral? it is like (x^2)' = 2x type of argument.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Please note that, in the integral, one psi dagger is with r and another one is with r', and the integral is over r'. So, my understanding is that: when doing the derivative with respect to psi^dagger(r,t), actually psi^dagger(r',t) does not work at all. So, there should be no 1/2. Even if psi^dagger(r',t) works for the derivative with respect to psi^dagger(r,t), it should give something like delta(r-r') and should make the integral disappear. So, I feel very confused. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: I think you should get \delta(psi^dagger(r,t) - psi^dagger(r',t)) because you are taking the derivative w.r.t. the field (psi^dagger) not r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be understood from the definition of functional variation, together with v(r-r')==v(r'-r) of Coulomb potential.

First of all, the functional derivative can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative
where you can find this:
[image: variation of F w.r.t. function rho]
Clearly, this gives the derivative of the Lagrange equation:

[image: Lagrange]

Next, let me define functional J as a function of function L:
[image: functional]

If we follow the definition of the functional derivative
by taking [image: variation of Psi]

we should have
[image: derivative]
(v(|r-r'|) is used; the derivative is exactly a mimic of fig.1 if you read the wiki carefully)

One interesting fact is that the 1/2 comes from the double-counting, and gets omitted by switching of r and r'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have got a similar results if looking at the L instead of the density. Then, what still confuses me is that: you know, given the Lagrange density (e.g., Eq. 1), the physical law can be deduced by Lagrange equation (e.g., Eq. 2). By considering Eq. 2 and Eq. 1 above, there is a 1/2 factor. Do you know why this 1/2 factor is there?